# Exception in callback trying to get WebResponse

Tags: httpwebrequest, silverlight-5.0, httpwebresponse

I am using HttpWebRequest to transfer files.  The workflow looks like this:

```
webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(WriteToStreamCallback), webRequest);
```

In WriteStreamToCallback:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;  
Stream requestStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
```

Write bytes to the requestStream, then call:

```
webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadHttpResponseCallback), webRequest);
```

The exception occurs in ReadHttpResponseCallback:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;  
// The next line throws a WebException
HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
```

The exception is:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.dll
>   The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

Can the app recover from this?  What might be the cause?  It is intermittent; is it a timing issue?
Thanks for any insight...

**UPDATE**:

```
private void ReadHttpResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        // The next line throws the exception
        HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);

        /* SNIP */
    }
    catch (WebException webEx)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("      {0} {1}", "ReadHttpResponseCallback - WebException", webEx.Message));
    }
    catch (Exception xx)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}  {1}", "ReadHttpResponseCallback", xx.Message));
    }
}
```

Comment: The file was not found.

Comment: leppie: Not found where?  Since I am writing to a stream to upload a file, did the stream become invalid since I obtained it?  It couldn't be referring to the local file, surely...

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed the fact that that is a first chance exception. That means it is being handled somewhere. It could be an internally handled exception or you might handle it.

Comment: Edited original to include outline of my ReadHttpResponseCallback() method.

Comment: Not sure :( How is the request setup? Is the server expecting that method?

Comment: I am sending large files in chunks.  This error appears intermittently; sometimes after 1 chunk is sent, or during the 16th, or not at all....

Answer (score 0):

May have found a solution here:  http://fearthecowboy.com/2011/09/02/fixing-webrequests-desire-to-throw-exceptions-instead-of-returning-status/